# DialogFlow error when launching Google Assistant Console

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using DialogFlow to build a Action for Google Assistant. I want to build this for pt-BR language, but when I am going to test the actions on Actions on Google console I'm getting the following error "Request contains an invalid argument. Locale pt-br selected but the language pt-BR has not been selected." as in the following image:

[image]

The steps for reproduce this issue:

1. Create a agent pt-BR language
2. Click on "See how it works on Google Assistant"

And the error appers at bottom of the browser window.

So guys, do anyone know the solution for this issue or a workaround?

Comment: It seems that this guy had the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384240/request-contains-an-invalid-argument-locale-pt-br-was-selected-but-the-language

Comment: It seems there's an issue going on on Google's side. There's already an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/123347859) created for this. Please star it for updates or provide more information if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123347859) haven't closed yet, but the problem was fix by the Google Team.